# How to present an alert for SimplePing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I have two ViewControllers one is ViewController and another one is GlobalViewController. I implemented SimplePing in GlobalVC to check net connection. It's working fine, but i want to show an alert when 'no internet'.

This is my code,

```
//In ViewController.m
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    //Calling SimplePing 'start' function
    [_gc checkNetConnection];    
}

//In GlobalVC
#pragma mark - SimplePingDelegate
- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", [error description]);
    NSLog(@"#####%@", error.localizedDescription);

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"No internet connection, please check it..." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) { }];
    UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
   [alert addAction:cancel];
   [alert addAction:ok];
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
   });
}
```

I'm getting this error,

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x146045800> on <GlobalViewController: 0x145e0e510> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Actually here I want to send my current ViewController to present alert, but i don't know how to send.

Can any one tell me answer in Swift or Objective c.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your GlobalViewController's view is not currently present in window. It's been replaced when you navigated to the ViewController.

If you want to show your alert in every other viewcontroller when internet is not available, you should define the alert as a category on UIViewController and then call it whenever you want to display it.

Something like this:

Select you project and then press 'Cmd + n' to add new file. Select Objective-C File

[image: new file]

Enter file name and save.

[image]

***Enter your code:***

**UIViewController+SimplePing.h**

```
@interface UIViewController (SimplePing)
- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailWithError:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

**UIViewController+SimplePing.m**

```
@implementation UIViewController (SimplePing)
- (void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", [error description]);
    NSLog(@"#####%@", error.localizedDescription);

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"No internet connection, please check it..." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) { }];
    UIAlertAction *cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
    [alert addAction:cancel];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
@end
```

Now you can call it from any of your viewcontroller.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to create UIViewController+SimplePing.h/.m files

Comment: Sure. Select your project, press cmd+n to add a new file. Select 'Objective-C File' in iOS menu. Next select 'Category' in the file type, select 'UIViewController' in class and enter file name.

Comment: @iOS I have updated the answer to tell how to add a category as well.

Comment: @ HAK, It's not displayng alert... Getting same problem. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: In ViewController Imported >h file and - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { UIViewController *vc= [[UIViewController alloc]init]; [vc alert];
}

Comment: @iOS Present it like this in viewDidAppear: [self alert];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171824/discussion-between-ios-and-hak).